# How to produce scatterplot of .txt file in R

Tags: r, input, scatter-plot

I am currently trying to produce a scatterplot of a .txt file that is structured like this in 25 rows:

```r
age income weight

33       63      180

25       72      220
```

however, when I try to convert it to a csv and then produce a scatterplot with the following code:

```r
my_input <- read.csv2('dataInput.txt', sep = '\t', header = T)

plot(x = my_input$ageX, y = my_input$weightY)
```

I get an error message. I also notice that there is now a period between 'age' 'income' and 'weight', which I don't understand since I would expect to get a comma between them. the error message is as follows:

> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values In addition:
>   Warning messages: 1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min;
>   returning Inf 2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max;
>   returning -Inf 3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min;
>   returning Inf 4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max;
>   returning -Inf

Any ideas on how to actually get a scatterplot of the data?

**Edit:** executing

```r
head(my_input)

age. income. weight
1  56     63     185
2  38     72     156
3  28     75     178
4  49     59     205
5  69     65     235
6  19     70     195
```

**Edit:**

```r
str(my_input)

age.income.weight: Factor w/ 18 levels "56  63     185",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

```r
summary(my_input)
age.income.weight

 56     63     185: 1     
 38     72     156: 1     
 28     75     178: 1     
 49     59     205: 1     
 69     65     235: 1     
 19     70     195: 1     
 (Other)          :19
```

Comment: sure, its up now

Comment: @dc37 Thanks, that seems to produce a scatterplot, although i'm not sure its providing the right output.

Comment: Well, when looking at the scatterplot I am getting a perfect straight line plot, but when looking at the numbers they are not 1:1 so I would not expect to get such a straight line, but more of a curved line or something.

Comment: @dc37 Picture has been added.

Comment: Your image show that your data were not plotted. You should check that your data are in a numerical format using `str(my_input)`

Comment: @dc37 df$age <- as.numeric(as.vector(df$age)) If I'm reading this  correctly this would not change the data type of the entire file, right? but only of the 'age' head of the table. I'm also getting'  Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion' now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203948/discussion-between-dc37-and-noobmaster69).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edits in your question, you have an issue in the loading of your txt file. While checking the structure of your text file, it appears that there is no consistent spacing between each row and columns.

So, one way to get it to work is to create the dataframe from scratch by read it using `readLines`:

```r
my_input <- readLines("crime_input.txt")
my_input <- unlist(strsplit(my_input," "))
```

Now you see that the file contains a lot of space:

```r
> my_input
  [1] "age"    "income" "crimes" "16"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "63"     ""       ""       ""      
 [13] ""       "23"     "18"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "72"     ""       ""       ""       ""      
 [25] "25"     "18"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "75"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "22"    
 [37] "19"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "59"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "16"     "19"    
 [49] ""       ""       ""       ""       "65"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "19"     "19"     ""      
 [61] ""       ""       ""       "70"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "19"     "20"     ""       ""      
 [73] ""       ""       "78"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "18"     "21"     ""       ""       ""      
 [85] ""       "35"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "11"     "21"     ""       ""       ""       ""      
 [97] "53"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "15"     "23"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "28"    
[109] ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       "9"      "27"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "56"    
[121] ""       ""       ""       ""       "16"     "28"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "52"     ""      
[133] ""       ""       ""       "14"     "29"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "63"     ""       ""      
[145] ""       ""       "25"     "30"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "46"     ""       ""       ""      
[157] ""       "17"     "30"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "55"     ""       ""       ""       ""      
[169] "19"     "31"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "29"     ""       ""       ""       ""       ""      
[181] "8"      "32"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "55"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "22"    
[193] "32"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "62"     ""       ""       ""       ""       "25"
```

So, we can convert everything to numeric, remove NA and get:

```r
my_input <- as.numeric(my_input)
my_input <- my_input[!is.na(my_input)]
```

To get:

```r
> my_input
 [1] 16 63 23 18 72 25 18 75 22 19 59 16 19 65 19 19 70 19 20 78 18 21 35 11 21 53 15 23 28  9 27 56 16 28 52 14
[37] 29 63 25 30 46 17 30 55 19 31 29  8 32 55 22 32 62 25
```

Finally, we can fill a matrix with this vector:

```r
my_input <- matrix(my_input, nrow = 3, ncol = length(my_input)/3)
```

```r
> my_input
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
[1,]   16   18   18   19   19   19   20   21   21    23    27    28    29    30    30    31    32    32
[2,]   63   72   75   59   65   70   78   35   53    28    56    52    63    46    55    29    55    62
[3,]   23   25   22   16   19   19   18   11   15     9    16    14    25    17    19     8    22    25
```

Now, we can transpose the matrix, transform as a data.frame and add colnames:

```r
my_input <- as.data.frame(t(my_input))
colnames(my_input) <- c("age","income","crimes")
```

And finally, you get:

```r
> head(my_input)
   age income crimes
1   16     63     23
2   18     72     25
3   18     75     22
4   19     59     16
5   19     65     19
6   19     70     19
```

And if you check the format of `my_input`:

```r
> str(my_input)
'data.frame':   18 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ age   : num  16 18 18 19 19 19 20 21 21 23 ...
 $ income: num  63 72 75 59 65 70 78 35 53 28 ...
 $ crimes: num  23 25 22 16 19 19 18 11 15 9 ...
```

So, now, you can plot it:

```r
my_input = my_input[order(my_input$age),]
plot(x = my_input$age, y = my_input$crimes, type = "b")
```

[image]

Now, you can work with this file. Hope it helps you to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you explain  why you use type = "b" and also why you perform the ordering?

Comment: Going to try in in the meanwhile

Comment: `type = "b"` means that I'm plotting both points and lines. Ordering is to get the    sequence of `age` values

Comment: I used the code and it works, the scatterplot is correct. However, I would have prefered to get a scattorplot without manually inserting the numbers in age = c() and weight = c().It feels like there is no use in even loading in the file if you're gonna do that, and this method won't work for large datasets.

Comment: I forgot to add that this solution does work for now, and apreciate your help and the code you provided. Thank you. I have also did what you said and used str() on input, and got the following: 
age.income.weight: Factor w/ 18 levels "number, number, number"

Comment: "Which solution " I mean that I was able to get a correct scatterplot, even though the solution is not perfect, that was my original goal.

Comment: I am not Quite sure whether the answer I got from the str(my_input) means is a string, since I'm not that great with R. If you could answer that and perhaps give a tip on how to convert the data to integers if they are strings that would be great.

Comment: Edited question to include str() and summary()

Comment: In the code you edited you are again manually inserting number to age <- c() and also for income and weight. This does allow me to get the scatterplot(which I have) but i would prefer to load the file and then say something like X = age and Y = crimes and then produce the scatterplot. This is a much more efficient end 'nice' way of doing it.